# Adding String to error enumeration to pass to controllers

Tags: swift, enums, enumeration

In the process of user login to the server, I defined an enumeration for errors

```
enum loginError: Error {
    case networkError
    case authorization
    case emptyUsernameOrPassword
}
```

And In the model, I add these error in the `completion` part. And this error send to the controllers.
For example here:

```
mutating func loginUser(completion: @escaping (Result<String,loginError>) -> Void ) {
    let urlString = loginUrl
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {fatalError()}

    let body: [String: Any] = [
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password,
        "client" : "time_tracker_chrome_extension",
        "device" : "iPhone",
        "device_type" : "Phone"
    ]


    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = body.percentEscaped().data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {
            //Check the response from the server
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
            }

            guard let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!) else {

                 //Here........
                completion(.failure(loginError.authorization))
                return
            }
```

How can I convert these error to `String`, then I send the `String` of this error to the controllers.

It's controller for this

```
@IBAction func pressLoginBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard usernameInput.hasText, passwordInput.hasText  else {return}

    let username = usernameInput?.text
    let password = passwordInput?.text
    var login = LogginReguest(username: username!, password: password!)

    login.loginUser { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let string):
            print(string)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really convert the error but you need some functionality to tie an error message to each error. Below is an example where the enum conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`

```
enum LoginError: Error, CustomStringConvertible {
    case networkError
    case authorization
    case emptyUsernameOrPassword

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .networkError:
            return "A network error occured"
        case .authorization:
            return "Not authorized"
        case .emptyUsernameOrPassword:
            return "Username or poassword not given"
        }
    }
}
```

Example

```
let error = LoginError.authorization
print(error)
```

prints

> Not authorized

but you could also have that `switch` in your controller class or implemented as a separate function.

Comment: It was a super great help. I am really appreciated.

Comment: Probably better to use `LocalizedError` rather than `CustomStringConvertible` which offers similar functionality but is meant to be used with errors

Comment: could you give me some example?